# Expected values of expected values when using sample statistics

Tags: statistics

Econometrics class was teaching properties of expected values and showing how they were used in some proofs. I decided to try and proof the variance formula for the variable W [e.g. W=aX+bY] and ran into a situation where I was taking expected values of expected values. I saw the answer to a question about taking the [expected value of an expected value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676599/expected-value-of-an-expected-value) and it made perfect sense. However, I got thinking and wondered if this only applied if you were looking at the population parameter rather than the sample statistic. A population parameter is a constant while a sample statistic is a random variable. Is the expected value of the sample statistic just going to equal the population parameter, thereby nulling the outer expected value, or is something going over my head?

Also, could you show me what the variance of W formula proof would look like if our random variables X and Y were sample statistics?

Comment: The expected value of the sample statistic is equal to the population parameter exactly when your sampling is unbiased.

Comment: What is the "variance of $W$ proof"?

Comment: @Neal: you also need your estimator to be unbiased